# Storing string arguments array in a list :java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Essentially, I want to have a method:

```
public void setArgs(String... vals)
{
    for (String s: vals)
        // Here I can add s every string passed to an array list
```

The thing I'm wondering is: can I simply store all of the arguments passed to `setArgs` in an Array, instead of bothering with an `ArrayList`? I know arrays are immutable in java, so I was wondering if you can somehow there's an easy way to extract the arguments without using a `loop`.

Thanks.

Comment: `> I know arrays are immutable in java`  
**Arrays are mutable, array size is not**

Comment: `"can I simply store all of the arguments passed to setArgs in an Array, instead of bothering with an ArrayList"` I think you mean the other way around.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, Using [`Arrays class asList() method`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29)

```
  List<String> argsList=  new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(vals));
```

Comment: Thank you! It says I need to wait 8 minutes to accept an answer (but it's 2AM now and I'm going to sleep). I'll close this in the morning =).